# Putting a string into a text file using file_put_contents outputs numbers

Tags: php

I want to put a php string into a text file but it only shows "0000" instead of the text I want.

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('servers.xml');

function GetServerStatus($site, $port)
{
$status = array("OFFLINE", "ONLINE");
$fp = @fsockopen($site, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
if (!$fp) {
    return $status[0];
} else 
  { return $status[1];}
}

$file = 'status.txt';
file_put_contents($file, "");

foreach ($xml->server as $server){
$content = $server->location & ": " & GetServerStatus($server->ip,80);
file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on $content line, in PHP, concatenation is done via dot operator ('.').

```
$content = $server->location . ": " . GetServerStatus($server->ip,80);
```